# Is there a kit that would allow me to replace a sealed beam headlamp with a halogen bulb?

Tags: toyota, lights, replace

In the future, I could just replace the bulb as needed without replacing the whole lamp.
This is for a 1997 Toyota Tacoma 4x4.

Answer (score 2):

I am showing that vehicle to already [take these halogen bulbs](http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_SilverStar-ULTRA-TWIN-Halogen-Headlight-Sylvania_5080137-P_1258_R%7CGRPLAMPAMS_____). If you have sealed beams and you want to upgrade the lights you can try for example [Hella Lights](http://www.myhellalights.com/index.php/default/upgrade-kits-and-accessories/sealed-beam-conversion-headlamps/vision-plus-conversion-headlamp/).